# CSS and Landscape

Tags: html, css

I'm new in programming and I'm trying to make my website, but I'm stuck with an issue:

When I opened my site in a **landscape page view**, a **blue column appear at the right side of it**. It's like it did not fit the 100% width of the page. When I scroll down, my sticky menu is able to fill it. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/user582/ycx56p4h/1/
```

[Site in googledevtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd4FV.png)

Comment: Please edit to ask one clear question per post.

Comment: Post any live link to your project or create a perfect fiddle so that code can be examined, Can't make sense out of Images ..!

Comment: This is not an answer, but I noticed you have an extra quotation mark in your HTML, after the href attribute: `<li><a href="#"" class="hvr-underline-from-center js--contact" id="contact">Contact</a></li>`
<br> Also, I recommend using jsfiddle to show us exactly what you mean (it might be hard for us to replicate your error otherwise).

Comment: please put all your code, or create a jFiddle.

Comment: Sorry, this it the jFiddle link of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/user582/ycx56p4h/1/

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve] otherwise it's [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic). Links to off-site resources are not enough as they may disappear which would make the question useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest answer to this would be that you need to restrain your page's width and hide all overflow. To do so, you can use:

```
html{
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The `vw` unit is quite unknown by people but is very useful as it matches the user's viewport width. Once you have set the `max-width`, you can hide all overflow on the x axis with `overflow-x`.

Comment: I included:  
* {
    max-width:100vw;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

and changed every width:100%; to width:100vw;

It solved the horizontal scroll, but creates a lot of vertical scrolls for my divs, paragraphs etc

Comment: You should not use the Universal `*` selector. Have you tried to apply those rules just to `html` and `body` ?